# Add Event to collection then fire all Events in that collection C#

Tags: c#, events

I'm starting to think I'm delving into the impossible.

So basically when a property is changed it will fire an event:

```
private DateTime _DateFrom;

public DateTime DateFrom
{
    get
    {
        return _DateFrom;
    }
    set
    {
        var oldValue = _DateFrom;
        _DateFrom = value;

        if (_DateFrom != oldValue)
        {
            //GetPropertyName is an extension method 
            //Used Specifically for notifying of priority changed fields
            NotifyPropertyChanged(ReflectionTypes.GetPropertyName(() => this._DateFrom));
        }
    }
}
```

Once subscribed will fire and then pass to a switch statement that determines which other events to fire. Because an event can appear twice, I would like to add an event to a collection and then fire all those events in the collection.

```
public void OnOpportuntiyPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{

    //Event Collection HERE?

    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
            //Remove hard coded strings and replace with reflection
        case "DateFrom":
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            break;
        case "SomeOtherChange":
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            break;
        case "MoreChanges":
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            //Event Name + Add to Event Collection
            break;
    }

    //Events will fire with successful subscription(from another location)
}
```

I cannot seem to get my head around this one, any help greatly appreciated! So to re-cap I would like to declare an events collection then iterate through the switch and then add to collection. Once the switch process has finished, I would like to fire all events in the collection.

**//EDITS**

So I'm hoping that explaining the process it will clear things up a little.

So on the UI layer within a form, a user changes the "DateFrom" field which then passes up to the "DateFrom" property (Opportunity Class). As this is a business critical change (Custom Travel CRM) an event needs to fire (NotifyPropertyChanged).

Once we hit the NotifyPropertyChanged event, it needs to determine which property has been changed. The idea is to snap in more than one business critical event hence adding to a collection.

The main reason for the collection is because more than one property type in the switch can have the same event and I don't want to fire those twice.

I hope this is cleared a few things up and more then happy to embark on a new path, if the "said" solution is not a appropriate.

In the original spec I forced the idea of events, so ideally need to make this work in the most extensible manner. Adding events to a collection was an idea inspired from the project manager.

Regards,

Comment: Maybe it is better to make more clarification to your question. e.g. adding code to show how you are adding event and what the event collection exactly is and so on.

Comment: "e.g. adding code to show how you are adding event and what the event collection exactly is and so on". Well that is the question, How? I'm asking how do i create the collection, how do add to the collection and how to fire all those in the collection.

Comment: this is a bit confusing. Can you start by explaining why you need an "event collection"? Who's gonna triggered those events?

Comment: @Leo This was a process the project manager advised, I'm simply trying to enforce and learn.

Comment: I'll Edit the Q, to explain better.

Comment: whats wrong with using normal events and losing the switch? ie DateChanged += DoX, DoY, DoXAgain... etc

Comment: Am I right in saying that you want some way of building a collection of `PropertyChanged` events for a series of related properties? So, `DateFrom` might also mean that `TotalDays`, for example, also should have a `PropertyChanged` event fired. And you want some way of building the list of property names that need to be fired for the event?

Comment: @Ewan I've edited the Q...More importantly DateChanged is certainly plausible as i would add that event if the property that was changed was the DateFrom property.

Comment: @Enigmativity I think that's almost it. More assigning events to the properties "That have been changed" So basically "If DateFrom has been changed" then apply multiple events and then add to collection. Once the switch has completed, fire all events in collection. Again everyone the idea was inspired by the project manager. I can change if it's not logical.

Comment: @TezWingfield - What kind of events? Not just `PropertyChanged`?

Comment: @Enigmativity apologies, If "DateFrom" was changed it changes the dynamics of a "trip" and is of high priority. So the idea would be to fire an event (May be OnPriorityListChanged) that more less notifies the department of the change/ Some other case inserts data/returns data/sends email. I'm trying to build it in a way that system becomes "plug-able". Iv'e chosen Events because I've never the used them before. Nice to learn something new.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I'm asking how do i create the collection, how do add to the
>   collection and how to fire all those in the collection

I think you can do what you want using a collection of `Action`. Here is the code:

```
//(1)create collection
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

switch (e.PropertyName)
{
    case "DateFrom":
        //(2)add to the collection
        actions.Add(new Action(() => {/* What you want to do in this case */ }));

    //....
}

//(3)fire all those in the collection
foreach (var item in actions)
{
    item();
}
```

Comment: @downvoter consider leaving a comment and say the reason